# passing textures to fragment shader in PIXI.js

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

How to pass and mix textures in fragment shader with PIXI.js?
I have a uniforms like this:

```
uniforms = {
      uResolution: new PIXI.Point(800, 600),
      texture: { value: new PIXI.Texture.from('img link here')}
    }
```

And I have this fragment shader:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

// Uniforms from Javascript
uniform vec2 uResolution;
uniform float uScrollProgress;

// The texture is defined by PixiJS
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
uniform sampler2D uSampler;
uniform sampler2D texture;


void main() {
  // Normalized coordinates
  vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / uResolution.xy;
  vec4 pixel = texture2D(texture, vTextureCoord);

  gl_FragColor = pixel;
}
```

What should I do in fragment shader, for example, to draw my texture on the screen? I have an error in my example now:

```
Uncaught TypeError: texture.castToBaseTexture is not a function
```

Comment: Not sure why you're including the [three.js] tag. I've removed since this question pertains to pixi.js, not three.js

Comment: Hey Spawni, it would be very helpful to see the PixiJS code you're using to set up for this fragment shader.  In particular, the default batch renderer uses a very limited set of uniforms for speed, and won't pick up on custom uniforms without rejiggering the render flow somewhat.  If you can slap your problem into a runnable sample it would help to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shader is trying to read a texture named `uSampler` but you never created that uniform name. Instead you named your uniform `texture`, which is never invoked in your shader code. Looks like simply renaming your uniform would fix your problem:

```js
uniforms = {
     uResolution: new PIXI.Point(800, 600),
     uSampler: new PIXI.Texture.from('img link here')
}
```

Comment: I think,  that uSampler was provided by PIXIjs by default. Because I have a previous canvas with some sprites. I want to draw new texture on this canvas, but I don't know how to do that

Comment: uSampler is a built-in uniform.  And the uniform shouldn't be set to {value:TEXTURE}, it should just be TEXTURE (not wrapped in an object).  See my answer for more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/73111831/4418836

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of Pixi.js rendering a texture inside of a shader

```js
// Create a pixi instance
const app = new PIXI.Application({ width: 800, height: 800 });
document.body.appendChild(app.view);
// Create the container that we will apply the shader to
var container = new PIXI.Container();
app.stage.addChild(container);


// Bring in some images
const spriteForShader = new PIXI.Sprite.from('https://assets.codepen.io/292864/internal/avatars/users/default.png?fit=crop&format=auto&height=512&version=1&width=512')
// This image is a random image from imgur (which has CORS enabled so Codepen can grab it)
const skyrimComic = new PIXI.Sprite.from('https://i.imgur.com/6BheBL1.jpeg')
// Note: The container must be rendering something in order for the shader to show,
// which is why we add this sprite to it.  It is a different sprite than spriteForShader
// to prove that the shader is rendering the spriteForShader ONLY via the texture uniform
// and not because it's a child.  Try removing the filter to see what it looks like without the
// shader applied
container.addChild(skyrimComic);

var shaderCode = `
  varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
  uniform sampler2D uTexture;

  void main(void) {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(uTexture, vTextureCoord);
    // Set the red to 0 just to show that the shader is having an effect
    // this will make the texture render without any red
    gl_FragColor.r = 0.0;
  }
`;
var uniforms = {
      // Pass the texture to the shader uniform
      // "uTexture" could be named whatever you want
      uTexture: spriteForShader.texture
}
var simpleShader = new PIXI.Filter('',shaderCode,uniforms);
container.filters = [simpleShader]
```

[See it working on Codepen](https://codepen.io/jdoleary/pen/KKovXjE?editors=1010)

Your problem is that you're passing in an object with a texture inside of it, rather than a texture.